Calling ReadFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable on HttpResponseMessage.Content throws ObjectDisposedException
Iterating over the result throws ObjectDisposedException if ReadFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable is returned directly:
 private static IAsyncEnumerable<Item?>GetItemsThrowsExeption(CancellationToken token = default)
 {
     using var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     using var fileStream = File.OpenRead("items.json");

     response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);

     return response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable<Item>(token);
 }

 public class Item
 { 
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

     public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
 }


By instead iterating over the result using an await for each, will trigger dispose the using statements after iteration has finished:
 private static async IAsyncEnumerable<Item?>GetItemsThrowsExeption([EnumeratorCancellation]CancellationToken token = default)
 {
     using var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     using var fileStream = File.OpenRead("items.json");

     response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);

     await foreach(var item in response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable<Item>(token))
     {
         yield return item;
     }
 }


